# AppSync console is extremely slow to update whenever I edit resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, vtl

Whenever I Edit Resolver in the AppSync console, and save, then execute the corresponding updated query, it keeps showing the previous results.

Like, I clicked "Save Resolver" multiple times, clicked the play button to execute query 20 times, refreshed 5+ times, still display the old result until I wait for a minute or so.

Any resolution to such inefficiency?  I can't debug properly with such level of inconsistency.

Comment: debugging with app sync in every way is inefficient. cant believe aws released it with such poor debugging capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a local instance using Amplify's [mocking capability](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/mock/) for faster turnaround during development. Note there are limitations:

- AFAIK you need to actually set up an Amplify project (read: create AWS resources) to mock, but these can be deleted after the initial setup
- Not all data source types are available